# javascript socket.io cannot get data

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have one element inside of the takimlar array. When i try to print it that way i get 1 printed out. But when i try to reach the takimlar value outside of the socket.on brackets.
i get 0 from the document write. I want to access the data that i take from the server in the client side but it seems i cant assign a variable on it. It is really interesting. Any help would be appreciated.

prints 1

```
var takimlar[];
var socket =io.connect();

socket.on('client_data13', function(data){ 

takimlar = data;
document.write(takimlar.length);

});
```

prints 0

```
var takimlar[];
var socket =io.connect();

socket.on('client_data13', function(data){ 

takimlar = data;


});
document.write(takimlar.length);
```

Comment: In second code, "Document.write(takimlar.length);" is placed outside of block in which variable takimlar defined in your code. So you second code returns lenght of implicitly defined variable 'takimlar'.

Comment: yes i understand that but how can i solve it?

Comment: you need to wait for socket to return data. Putting the document.write out side the on wont return the result.